# Solve laravel migration problem with foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, migration

I wrote the migrations and they worked well until i tried to make them `on delete cascade`
i added `$table->engine = 'InnoDB'` and that was ok.
but in seeders, when i tried to run them i got an error

```
 PDOException::("SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mohajerat`.`comments`, CONSTRAINT `comments_comment_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`comment_id`) REFERENCES `comments` (`id`) ON
 DELETE CASCADE)")
```

i know there is some questions in stackoverflow but non of them helped me. So i asked here to anyone can help
this is my migration:

```
  Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->morphs('commentable');
            $table->string('body', 250);
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('comment_id')->constrained('comments')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

and this is my seeder:

```
    Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
        Comment::truncate();
        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
        $users = \App\Models\User::all()->toArray();
        foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
//            $comment = \App\Models\Comment::all()->random();
            $post = \App\Models\Article::all()->random();
//            dd($user, $post);
            factory(Comment::class)->create([
                'user_id' => $user['id'],
                'commentable_id' => $post->id,
                'commentable_type' => get_class($post),
                'comment_id' => 0
            ]);
        }
```

please tell me if you know. 
thanks!

Comment: Where are the column declarations that your foreign keys reference?? You’ve created a foreign key but haven’t assigned it to any column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** Your foreign key table must be created before you assign them. Check the image and code.

> In my products table I have added "product_categories" and "product_brands" as a reference table. I have created "products_categories" and "product_brands" migration before creating "products" table.
>
> [image]

Product Table with foreign key

```
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title')->unique();
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('brand_id');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->text('information')->nullable();
        $table->integer('stock');
        $table->bigInteger('price');
        $table->bigInteger('sale_price')->nullable();
        $table->string('sku')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('product_categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('brand_id')->references('id')->on('product_brands')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```